# Database data automatically deleted by hibernate in many to many relation

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I have an application using `Struts2`, `Spring` and `Hibernate`. I have entities with a `Many-to-Many` relationship. When I try to retrieve data, `Hibernate` deletes all data in db. And in the log file I found this :

```
Hibernate: select composantc0_.commandeFournisseur_id as commande2_3_1_, composantc0_.composantCommandeClient_id as composan1_0_1_, composantc1_.id as id1_4_0_, composantc1_.commandeClients_id as commande2_4_0_, composantc1_.medicamentsFournisseurs_id as medicame3_4_0_, composantc1_.quantite as quantite4_4_0_, composantc1_.dateCommande as dateComm5_4_0_, composantc1_.presentation as presenta6_4_0_, composantc1_.prix as prix7_4_0_ from commandefournisseur_has_composantcommandeclient composantc0_ inner join salama.composantcommandeclient composantc1_ on composantc0_.composantCommandeClient_id=composantc1_.id where composantc0_.commandeFournisseur_id=?
Hibernate: delete from commandefournisseur_has_composantcommandeclient where commandeFournisseur_id=?
Hibernate: select medicament0_.id as id1_6_0_, medicament0_.fournisseurs_id as fourniss2_6_0_, medicament0_.prix as prix3_6_0_, medicament0_.designation as designat4_6_0_, medicament0_.laboratoire as laborato5_6_0_, medicament0_.datePeremption as datePere6_6_0_, medicament0_.tva as tva7_6_0_, medicament0_.disponible as disponib8_6_0_ from salama.medicamentfournisseur medicament0_ where medicament0_.id=?
Hibernate: select medicament0_.id as id1_6_0_, medicament0_.fournisseurs_id as fourniss2_6_0_, medicament0_.prix as prix3_6_0_, medicament0_.designation as designat4_6_0_, medicament0_.laboratoire as laborato5_6_0_, medicament0_.datePeremption as datePere6_6_0_, medicament0_.tva as tva7_6_0_, medicament0_.disponible as disponib8_6_0_ from salama.medicamentfournisseur medicament0_ where medicament0_.id=?
```

The relationship in Commandefournisseur

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "commandefournisseur_has_composantcommandeclient", catalog = "salama", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "commandeFournisseur_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)}, inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "composantCommandeClient_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)})
@JsonIgnore
public Set getComposantcommandeclients() {
    return this.composantcommandeclients;
}
```

And in composantCommandeClient

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "commandefournisseur_has_composantcommandeclient", catalog = "salama", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "composantCommandeClient_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)}, inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "commandeFournisseur_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)})
@JsonIgnore
public Set getCommandefournisseurs() {
    return this.commandefournisseurs;
}
```

My Struts2 Action

```
public String details() {
    commandefournisseur = commandefournisseurService.find(commandeFournisseurId);
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

My Dao method

```
public T find(Integer id)  {
    return (T) getHibernateTemplate().get(getEntityClass(), id);
}
```

In my view

```
<s:iterator value="commandefournisseur.composantcommandeclients">
                            <tr>
                                <td><s:property value="medicamentfournisseur.designation" /></td>
                                <td><s:property value="prix" /></td>
                                <td><s:property value="quantite" /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </s:iterator>
```

Does someone know how to disable this auto delete? I'm using hibernate 4.2.7.Final

**EDIT :** When i use eager instead of lazy loading it works. So why data is deleted in lazy loading?

Comment: How do you know that 'auto-delete' is enabled (whatever it is), so that it needs to be 'disabled'? Also, please post your attempts to solve the issue, it will help others to give you a more accurate answer.

Comment: I add all code in post. I think it is auto delete because there is no delete process in a code that i write.